# Какой вопрос можно выбрать?

Tags: сказуемое

В предложении КНИГА ЛЕЖИТ НА СТОЛЕ какой вопрос можно задать к сказуемому?

Comment: Книга (что делает?) лежит.

Comment: Книга, подлежащее, выраженное существительным неодушевлённым.Знаем, что неодушевлённые предметы не могут быть производителем какого-либо действия. В этом отношении, мне кажется, вопрос ЧТО ДЕЛАЕТ? нельзя задавать к сказуемому. Прямого вопроса нет. Извините, немножко смешно получается. Я слышал, что,хотя косвенно, но такой вопрос более уместный: О каком положении книги говорится в предложении?

Comment: В действительности, конечно, все  именно так и есть. Но ведь, когда мы определяем род существительного, для облегчения этой задачи добавляя "он мой" или "она моя", мы не придираемся к тому факту, что объект, обозначаемый существительным, род которого нам необходимо определить, на самом деле нам не принадлежит.

Comment: "Неодушевлённые предметы не могут быть производителем какого-либо действия",-пишете Вы. А разве не являются производителями действий многообразные механизмы? Автомобиль движется, теплоход идет, компьютер работает...

Comment: Все тела, *живые* и *неживые*, взаимодействуют друг с другом. Они все время **что-то делают**)))  
Вопрос, кто в этом *виноват*, является основным в философии.

Comment: Лежать — глагол состояния. К сказуемому в исходном предложении можно поставить вопрос: "Что происходит?" Ответ: **лежит** книга. Если придираться к форме вопроса, то усмотреть в нём номинацию *действия* тоже, конечно, можно. И поставить вопрос развёрнуто: "В каком состоянии находится?" Ответ: *лежит*. Вопрос в этом случае длиннее, а ответ короче. Выбор, полагаю, равноправен.

Comment: Грамматика - наука обобщенная и формальная, она дает нам модели (отвлеченные образцы), в которые мы вкладываем  конкретное содержание. Определяя роль глагола в предложении, мы отвлекаемся от его конкретной лексики и соотносим с глаголом "делать", которое в ОБЩЕМ ВИДЕ представляет  различные действия и процессы. Не стоит также забывать о том, что вопросы вида  ЧТО ДЕЛАЕТ используются только в школьной практике, когда учащиеся не имеют достаточного опыта отвлеченного мышления. А в общей  грамматике мы имеем предмет и его процессуальный признак, которые образуют предикативную основу предложения.

Comment: Вот! Наконец-то кто-то на языке науки объяснил ситуацию (это я о комментарии Софии). Возможно, однако, что автору вопроса необходимо задать вопрос к сказуемому не для того, чтобы найти его в предложении, а для того, чтобы построить новое вопросительное предложение. В этом случае будет предпочтительнее формулировка вопроса, предложенная самим автором (а именно: "О каком положении книги говорится в предложении?").

Answer (score 1):

В младших классах, говоря о подлежащем и сказуемом, приучают говорить: О ком или о чём идёт речь в предложении?- о книге. Что о ней говорится?-что она лежит. Где?-на столе.